# How to trigger two commands when pressing a key bind

Tags: configuration, tmux, clipboard, buffer

So I wanted to pass the text stored in my buffer through a socket to other machine, for that I manage to get a socket done, I just need to fire up the following command when in `copy-mode-vi`

```
bind -T copy-mode-vi Enter send-keys -X copy-selection-and-cancel \; run-shell "tmux loadb - | nc localhost 19988"
```

I have already seen that it is supose to be with `\;` but this syntax is making my tmux malfunction.

Answer (score 0):

[-X only accepts one command at a time](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/774#issuecomment-279161707), but fortunately, you can bind multiple `send-keys -X` commands (separated via `\;`)

```
bind -T copy-mode-vi Enter send-keys -X copy-selection-and-cancel \; send-keys -X run-shell "tmux loadb - | nc localhost 19988"
```

However, there's a second problem; only certain commands are supported in copy mode, and `run-shell` is not among them. Only the three `copy-pipe` allow you to invoke an external command (and it has to accept and process the selection), so you need to completely redesign your approach here, unfortunately.